# How can I use SqLite with BlackBerry OS 4.5?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

I am currently using Persistent Storage in BlackBerry. I want to use SqLite Database with BlackBerry OS 4.5, but I cannot find any tutorial for that. Can I use SqLite with BlackBerry OS 4.5 or do I need another version of BlackBerry OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no SqLite support for BlackBerry OS 4.5.
BlackBerry OS 5.0 introduces SqLite support. For more information, see RIM's [SQLite overview](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8682/SQLite_overview_701956_11.jsp)

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options at your disposal

The Sybase solution [UltraLiteJ](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/sqlanywhere/blackberry)

Or McObject solution [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/j2me_database/)

Answer (score 1):

Sybase sells a DB for BlackBerry 4.1 and higher.